# Ruby on Rails: nested routes, :id getting nil, but it is in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I'm not sure where to start with this problem. I have images with nested routes, example:

```
localhost:3000/users/1/images/3
localhost:3000/users/1/images/4
```

When I go into the first image (id = 3), it works. But when I go to the second image (id = 4) I get a routing error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"images", :user_id=>1, :id=>nil}
```

I have other images too (from previous upload), now when I upload other images, I get nil for my id.

When I check my database, it shows that the data is in there, and it does have the correct row with id 4.

Has this happened to anyone? Is there some kind of `rake` command that I can use? This is baffled and I don't even know where to start showing my code to see where the error is coming from

EDIT:

```
user_image GET    /users/:user_id/images/:id(.:format)         images#show
```

**routes.rb:**

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :images do
      resources :comments, :defaults => { :commentable => 'image' }
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT:

I figured out the issue.. Apparently it was a path that was in my show.html.erb view where I'm trying to get the "next" image from my database and that there's no id to get

```
<%= link_to "Next", user_style_path(@image.user_id, @image.next_img) if user_style_path(@image.user_id, @image.next_img) %>
```

Where in my model I have:

```
  def previous_img
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", created_at], :order => "created_at desc")
  end

  def next_img
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", created_at], :order => "created_at asc")
  end
```

How do I reverse back to the images ONLY associated with the user, so that it'll just recycle the images?

Comment: It's looks like your path helper has been called using one argument. Your path have to be `users_image_path(1, 4)` where `1` is `:user_id` and `4` is `:id`

Comment: @ck3g Yeah, I have my path that way. It does have two arguments. I have some images that does work, and some that shows the routes error with id nil

Comment: If you actually type in the route `localhost:3000/users/1/images/4` can you get to the page for that image?

Comment: @bgates No, only a few id's that work, I'm using id 4 as an example, which gets the `Routing Error`

Comment: Does `rake:routes` say you have any constraints on that kind of route?

Comment: @bgates I don't think there are any constraints, I've never seen any constraints before. What does a constraint look like?

Comment: Put another way, what do your `routes.rb` and the output of `rake:routes` look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34124/discussion-between-bgates-and-andrewliu)

Comment: Please show how you build the url, and how the variables are set. Are you sure you are handing down valid values?

Comment: @nathanvda this is how my url for images are set `<%= link_to image_tag(i.image_url(:images)), user_image_path(@user, i.id) %>`, where `:images` is from carrierwave upload file, `@user` is the user id which in this case is `1`, and `i.id` is the id of the image, which in this case is either `3` or `4`, but id = 4 is the one that's causing routing error, while `3` works
`

Comment: But if `i.id==4`, you would not get the error it produces. Are you sure `i.id` is a valid number (because you mentioned before in your that 4 was just an example). So for test write `link_to image_tag(i.image_url(:images)), '#'`. Could it be possible that id is not yet set (not yet saved?). Just thinking out loud here :)

Comment: What do the ImagesController#show action and images/show view look like?

Comment: @bgates I'm an idiot, I figured out that there has to something to do with a path I have in my show page. I updated my OP if you think you might be able to help? Thanks so much

Comment: @nathanvda I figured it out! I updated my OP if you might think you're able to help. It was an error from my show page :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: OK, you can get out of that by making the methods on the model class methods:

```
def self._next(img)
  first(:conditions => ["created_at > ?", img.created_at], :order => "created_at asc") || first
end
```

and then scoping them to the user in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Next", user_style_path(@image.user_id, @user.images._next(@image)) unless @user.images == [@image] %>
```

Rails will combine the scopes for you. Note that I'm assuming you have a @user or a current_user or something available, and also that the class method is #_next not #next, because "next" is a reserved keyword.

The way #_next is structured, if it can't actually find the next image (the first created newer than the current), that clause will be nil, and it will return the first image of the collection instead. The link will be active unless there's only one image in the collection at first I had thought to make it active unless the collection is empty, but I guess it can't be empty or you wouldn't be on the page in the first place.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this answer, but I'm stil getting an :id => nil. I believe its because its trying to get the next id which isn't available in my database yet. If I'm on the last image in my database (for this specific user), how do I make the next button go back to the first image (from the database) of this user?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Try adding `|| first` at the end of the #_next method. Changing `if user_style_path...` to `unless @user.images.empty?` would be a good idea too, because that's the next point at which the code will complain.

Comment: hmm, it seems like I'm not getting it, can you update your post? I'd like to compare what I'm doing. It seems like I'm either still getting the nil, or the link doesn't appear at all. What about if there's some kind of if/else statement in the model, where if images is at the last id, then find the first image from record?

Comment: I'm going to check this answer, I posted another question regarding my new issue. But this got me in the right direction, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your id is listed as *null*, which indicates to me that you may not have first identified your Image object in the *show* action of your ImageController before going to your *show* view.

Put

```
@image = @user.images.find(params[:id])
```

in your *show* controller action and see what happens. If not already defined, @user should be

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

If that doesn't work, then it could be a routing problem. Ensure that you have the correct nested resources in your config/routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :images
end
```

Otherwise, check your associations: your User class should have a **has_many** relation to images, and your Image class should have a **belongs_to** relation to users.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I had exactly what you suggested. Again, my issue only happens to some images, which I don't know why...